# Text in different locations on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in the process of creating a keyboard.  I was kindly wondering how I can have a button with a letter in both the middle and also in the upper left-hand corner? Right now I can have one following the other. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
    <button name = "Q" id = "alphabet"> Q &#x1107</button>
    <button name = "Q" id = "alphabet"> W &#x110C </button>
    <button name = "Q" id = "alphabet"> E &#x1103</button>
    <button name = "Q" id = "alphabet"> R &#x1100</button>
    <button name = "Q" id = "alphabet"> T &#1109</button>
```

Comment: Is almost impossible to help you without seeing your current code, layout and desired result. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question

Comment: Do you mean a button with mulitple characters like many international keyboards?

Comment: How about `<sup>up</sup>`?  (obviously, you could use further css styling, primarily `position`ing, depending on your needs)

Comment: Yes I am trying to make a Korean keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

Position two spans relative to the button. One of the spans holds the letter to go in the middle, the other holds the letter to go in the top left. Than you can move the spans absolutely to be where you'd like.

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height:30px;
  position: relative;
}
button > .middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

button > .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>
<span class="middle">M</span>
<span class="top-left">T</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display your button value like this :" <sup>**q**</sup> **Q** ".

If your point is this just use `<sup>` in html . so your code should be :

```
 <button name = "Q" id = "alphabet"><sup>q</sup> Q </button>
```

Hope this resolve your problem .